# Create Bitmap with Matrix from Image

Tags: android, image, matrix, bitmap

I want to cut a piece of an Image with a fixed aspect ratio.

The user can choose the area which should be cutted out within a WYSIWYG view.

The final output should be a bitmap with fixed resolution (1300px * 1000px).

The aspect ratio of the WYSIWYG view and the output bitmap is the same.

[Preview Image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q5t0tw8s6367h8u/2015-03-21%2010.39.08.png?dl=0)

Simple solution would be upscale the bitmap from the WYSIWYG view to output resolution (would work because aspect ratio is the same) but i want to cut the choosen area from the original input bitmap.

I think the cropper: [Cropper](https://github.com/edmodo/cropper) is doing the same

How to do that ?

Comment: How to do what?  How to scale a matrix?

Comment: adapt the matrix from resolution A to resolution B btw. adapt the scale factor

Comment: Yep, tried{matrix.postScale(scale / previewWidth * outputWidth, scale / previewHeight * outputHeight);} but doesnt work

Comment: postScale does work,  why wouldn't it?

Comment: could you please look at my preview image, perhaps its more clear what i am looking for

Comment: Sorry,  that image doesn't help much

Comment: Edited my question... hope it is more clear now what to do